# Dynamically set comparison rules in a conditional?

Tags: php, dynamic

I have three rules that the user can configure:

1- As active or not, if it's active I have to use it in the conditional.

2- The user can set the rules behaviour as '&&' or 'or'.

3- Finally the user can set the value of the rule.

For instance, with this rules set;

Rule 1, active: yes, behaviour: or, value 15.

Rule 2, active: yes, behaviour: or, value 35.

Rule 3, active: yes, behaviour: or, value 55.

I have to build a conditional like 
this:

```
if($varX < 15 or $varY < 35 or $varZ < 55)
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

How can I acomplish this?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your logic. `$var < 15 or $var < 35 or $var < 55` is equal to `$var < 55` because as long as it's less than 55, it's true for all three.

Comment: Sorry I already changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t try and “build” such a statement dynamically and execute it (that’s gonna be fragile) – rather figure out the result of the expressions individually, and connect their values by and/or afterwards …

Something like this, (pseudo code)

```
result = true;
if(rule_active) {
  if(rule_behavior is or) {
    result || (rule_var < rule_value);
  }
  else {
    result && (rule_var < rule_value);
  }
return result or do whatever with it …
```

(Exchanged `and` for `&&` and `or` for `||` here, since using those is more common; you can of course keep `and` and `or` in their place if you like, you just need to be aware of the different operator precedence.)

Of course this might still problematic, if you don’t simply want to join the result of one rule to the next one-by-one in the order they come in, but also take into account that `and` has a higher precedence than `or` in boolean logic … but that wasn’t part of your question so far.
If you want to account for that as well, then you’ll need to figure out the right “order” in which to do the checking and joining beforehand. (And even then, the result might not be what the user had in mind – so perhaps you will need to find a way to let the user introduce “parentheses” for grouping into building the rule sets as well …? Really depends on the complexity of the actual task at hand.)